# Js and wordpress help...where does it go?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, hide

So ive been putting off using js for a while because everytime I try to figure it out I get more confused, but now I really need it for a site im working on...

I want to hide the page until everything loads (so you don't see elements moving/jumping into place.

I've found various bits on here and around the web, but everytime I go to place the code anywhere that I feel it should go, I get errors.

take this for example:

```js
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById('loading-mask').style.display='none';
}
```

Ive tried going to the functions.php file and adding the js code i've found on the web but always get an error. So where do I copy the code for this, so it affects the CSS ive added?

Comment: What does the error say? Is the element with id 'loading-mask' found when this function runs?

Comment: _“I want to hide the page until everything loads (so you don't see elements moving/jumping into place.”_ - bad idea. All it needs then is one simple little error (that you can perhaps not even reproduce or foresee on your test devices), and you could end up with the user not getting to see anything at all any more.  Stuff doesn’t “jump around” that much anyway to begin with, if the styling is constructed properly.

Comment: Tools like Google PageSpeed will probably not like such an artificial and unnecessary delay either … (And you are aware that exactly this kind of perceived “speed” in page build-up is one of the factors Google uses to rank sites, right?)

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress, you need to use a plugin to help you insert your javascript/jquery

1. Login to wordpress
2. Go to plugins>>add new
3. Search for  [Insert Headers and Footers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/) plugin
4. Install and activate
5. Then launch the plugin and insert your javascript.
6. You will need to select the location of your javascript, either in the  tag or just before the closing

Answer (score 0):

When you add javascript to a wordpress website, you want to do it in one of two ways. You can either do it using a hook which is essentially a 'spot' in the code you wish to add to.

This can be done by placing the following in your **functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wp_54885300_add_js_to_header');

function wp_54885300_add_js_to_header(){ ?>
    <script>

    window.onload=function() {
        document.getElementById('loading-mask').style.display='none';
    }

    </script>
<?php
}
```

Alternatively, if you find yourself needing to place lots of javascript into your website, you may wish to link to an external javascript file. This can be done with [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Place the following in your **functions.php** file to enqueue an external stylesheet to your website.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_54885300_enqueue_script' );
function wp_54885300_enqueue_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script('anyname', 'path-to-file.js', array(''), 'version', false ); 
}
```

As others have pointed out, what you are trying to do by hiding everything until the window has completely loaded may not be a good idea for a number or reasons.

But, atleast to the best of my knowledge, *this ^^* is the proper way to include JS into a wordpress installation without depending on a plugin to get you started.